# Where is the source code for gcc-g++ stored on windows when installing through Cygwin?

Tags: windows, gcc

I installed gcc-g++ through Cygwin on Windows 10. If you've ever used Cygwin on Windows, just before installing, it provides a huge list of different applications that can be used with it. Most of them, in addition to checking their install box, you can also check the source code box. I assumed this meant that it stores the source code of the application so that we can review it in order to understand how it's working.

I checked the box for gcc-g++, and I checked their source code box. However, when looking through the Cygwin installation folder, I can't seem to find where the source code is for the gcc-g++ application.

I was hoping that someone out there knew what folder their source code is stored in when installing through Cygwin to a Windows machine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

all cygwin source packages should be installing under `/usr/src`.